# Static vs Dynamic Binding Logic

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    { 
        B a = new A(); 

        a.p(10);  
        a.p(10.0); 
    } 
} 
    class B { 
        public void p(double i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i*2); 
        } 
    }

    class A  extends B{ 
        public void p(int i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
    }
```

When I execute this code using `B a = new A()` , I get 20.0 in both cases which makes sense because overloading is handles during compile time where the compiler looks at the declared type and calls a function appropriately. Since our declared type was class B, class B's method was called in both cases. Now if I do `A a = new A();` , I should be getting 10 in both answers but I am not. I am getting 10 for `a.p(10)` and 20.0 for `a.p(10.0)`. Based on the concept of static binding and whole notion of overloading being done by static binding which looks at the declared type as opposed to the actual type, why is the result coming out this way ?  I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, your are doing overloading which will get binded at compile time(static binding.).And static binding happens with type of reference rather than the type of object the reference is pointing.
In your first case you are using a reference variable of B and assigning an object of A to it.Since your reference is B, the method p(double) from B will get binded statically even if you use an int(since int can be widened to double).

In the second case you are using reference as A itself.In this case, you have two p() methods available.One is p(double) from B and other p(int) from A.So p(10) will call p(int) and p(10.0) will call p(double)

Try this:

```
class B { 
    public void p(String i) 
    { 
        System.out.println("parent:"+i); 
    } 
}

class A  extends B{ 
    public void p(int i) 
    { 
        System.out.println(i); 
    } 
} 
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

         A a = new A(); //arg
            a.p(10);  
            a.p("sample"); 
    }
}
```

If you change the line marked arg to B a = new A(), you will see compiler trying to call parent p in both the cases.

Comment: if what you are saying is correct, then if I change my subclass method to public void p(double i) { System.out(i*3);}, and then if I invoke B a = new A(), I should be getting 20.0 in both cases  but why am I getting 30.0? Why is the compiler looking at the subclass method? I will appreciate your help.

Comment: In that case, you are overriding the function which is dynamic binding.In the case of dynamic binding, it the object type not the reference which determines which method to call at runtime.So in that case,both your method invocations will be calling the over ridden method in sub class.Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Ahh! you are right my friend. You got it. Thanks alot for the answer. You guys rock!!

Comment: `int` widening to `double` was very vital. i'm sure lost in concept of overloading at compile time one can easily forget to take note of this.

Answer (score 2):

An `int` can be widened to a `double`, but not the other way around.  This means that `10` can call `B.p(double)` or `A.p(int)` but `10.0` is a `double` and will not be implicitly converted to an `int` i.e. only `B.p(double)` will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Its because your method `p` is not an overridden method, it is just inhereted in your sub-class when you use

```
Super sup = new Sub();
sup.p(int);
sup.p(double);
```

In this case as your Super class has a method which takes double as a parameter and aa an **int** can **fit into** a `double` your Super-class's method is invoked the one which accepts double.

```
Sub sup = new Sub();
sup.p(int);
sup.p(double);
```

In this case however, as your subclass doesn't have a method which takes a double, for `sup.p(double) call` it uses the inherited method from super class if you pass double as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `A a = new A()` you create a new object of type `A`, which will have 2 methods. `A.p(int)` and `B.p(double)`, and when you call `A.p(10.0)`, it will call `B.p(double)` due to lack of conversion.

Comment: Thanks Ashwin for the anwer

Answer (score 1):

This counter-example might help:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class X
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    { 
        B c = new A(); 

        c.p(10);  
        c.p(10.0); 
        c.p("AAA");
        ((A)c).p(10);
    } 
} 
    class B { 
        public void p(String s) 
        { 
            System.out.println("B: my string is " + s); 
        } 

       public void p(double i) 
        { 
            System.out.println("B: twice my double is: " + i*2); 
        } 
    }

    class A  extends B{ 
        public void p(int i) 
        { 
            System.out.println("A: my number is " + i); 
        } 
    }
```

Output:

```
C:\temp>java X
B: twice my double is: 20.0
B: twice my double is: 20.0
B: my string is AAA
A: my number is 10
```

The issue is:

1) You're declaring the type as "B" (not "A")

2) B.p(10) *can* accept an int as a floating point argument

3) Consequently, that's what you're getting

It's really an issue of what argument types can be implicitly converted, than what methods are overloaded or overridden.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Appreciate your time

Answer (score 1):

When the object has declared type `B`, the `double` version is invoked because it's compatible with an `int` argument, since in Java `int` is a subtype of `double`.

When the object is declared as a `A`, it has the method `p()` overloaded with two versions:

```
p(int arg);
p(double arg);
```

So, when you pass an `int`, the first version is picked because it's more accurate, and when you pass `double` the second one, because it's the most specific signature.

For reference, see the relevant [JLS at §15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html) and [this post by Gilad Bracha](http://gbracha.blogspot.it/2009/09/systemic-overload.html). BTW, don't try to figure out how the language should behave based on what you think is the most *logical* way, because every programming language is an engineering effort, and this means that there's a price you pay for whatever you take. The primary source of information for Java are the JLS, and if you read it carefully, you'll (surprisingly?) discover that there are even cases where the line in the source code is ambiguous and cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

To make the effect of widening of int to double more vivid I have created another example which is worth looking. Here, instead of `double` I have created a class called `Parent` and instead of `int` a `Child` class is created.

Thus,
double ~ Parent 
 int~Child

Obviously child object can be widened to Parent reference.

```
package test;
public class OOPs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child ch = new Child(); // like int 10
        Parent pa = new Parent();// like double 10.0

        B a = new A(); // case 2 : A a = new A();

        a.p(ch);// 10
        a.p(pa);// 10.0
    }
}

class B {
    public void p(Parent i) {
        System.out.println("print like 20");
        System.out.println(i.getClass().getName());
    }
}

class A extends B {
    public void p(Child i) {
        System.out.println("print like 10");
        System.out.println(i.getClass().getName());
    }
}

class Parent {
    String name;

    Parent() {
        name = "Parent";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    String name;

    Child() {
        name = "Child";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Case 1 - Output** `(B a = new A();)`
print like 20
test.Child
print like 20
test.Parent

**Case 2 - Output** `(A a = new A();)`
print like 10
test.Child
print like 20
test.Parent